# Multiple processes accessing worklist using EF in SQL Server safely

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table in SQL server that contains a list of small tasks that are constantly being added to.  A process that uses Entity Framework queries the list tasks for uncompleted tasks, selects one, completes it, and updates the task status.  I'd like to run multiple processes on a number of machines so that the tasks can be completed, but there is a risk that two processes might select the same task from the table, which would lead to problems.  I can't use concurrent primitives since task consumers run in different processes on different machines.  Is there an accepted pattern for how to do this?  I think I'd need to do something like try to set the task to "in progress" and then make sure no other process did the same thing, but I'm wondering if there's a straightforward way to do this using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a column of type timestamp/rowversion to the table and set up your table configuration to let entity framework know this column will be used for optimistic concurrency.  This column works by incrementing each time that an update is made to the row in the database.  When one of your processes has an instance of the entity it was have the value of the timestamp column when it was obtained.  When Entity Framework attempts to update this row in the database, it will append an additional check to the where clause that specifies the timestamp to be the value of what it was when it obtained the entity from the database.  If the values do not match, then an OptimisticConcurrencyException will be thrown since the row has changed.

Here's an example of a set-up for an entity with optimistic concurrency (Store-Wins)

```
public class Foo 
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }

    // ...Other instance members

    public byte[] ConcurrencyCheck { get; private set; }
}

public class FooConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Foo>
{
    public FooConfiguration()
    {
        Property(t => t.ConcurrencyCheck)
            .IsRowVersion();
    }
}
```

This link will take you to some of the design patterns for optimistic concurrency with Entity Framework

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would use InProgress flag just as you mentioned together with a transaction with isolation level REPEATABLE READ so that two process can't read the same task as "free".

You can use TransactionScope class which is natively supported by EF.

I'm afraid there is nothing more straigforward can be done here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **optimistic concurrency management** and let EF detect the conflict, throw an exception and then handle it. It is worth to mention, that with this solution the conflict will only raise when the computation is ready.
Here is an article about the topic: [Handling Concurrency with the Entity Framework 4.0](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/continuing-with-ef/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-web-application)

You can also use **pessimistic concurrency management** and lock the selected row for update when initializing a task. EF does not support pessimistic concurrency management, and it can also be database engine specific.

You can also implement a custom "locking mechanism". As you suggested you can do this by tracking the state of a task in a separate field. To prevent multiple processes to enter the "in progress" state, you can use optimistic concurrency management. This solution is an upgraded version of a native optimistic concurrency handling, as the conflict will be raised before the task is initialized to compute on the client.